# Show that : $ \sup_{x\in \overline{\text{co}} (A)}\|x\|=\sup_{x\in A} \|x\| $

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space and $A\subset X$.

> Show that :
>
> $$
>  \sup_{x\in \overline{\text{co}} (A)}\|x\|=\sup_{x\in A} \|x\|
> $$

with :
$$
\overline{\text{co}}(A)=\overline{\{y~:~y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_ix_i~,~\text{with}~\lambda_i\in[0,1]~, ~\text{such that}~\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_i}=1,~\text{and }x_i\in A,~n\in\mathbb{N} }\}}
$$
An idea please.

Answer (score 2):

How about

$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ix_i\right\|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i\|x_i\|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i\sup_{x\in A}\|x\| = \sup_{x\in A}\|x\|$$

The reverse inequality is even simpler